# Is it possible to subscript an array literal at the point of definition?

Tags: python, c, syntax

I'd like to subscript an array literal at the point of definition, since I don't need the array after that initial access:

```
int func(int index) {
   return {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[index];
}
```

Note: the array elements are more complex than this example. Also I'm omitting boundary checks. I'm simply curious whether the C syntax allows this kind of construct/shortcut.

Compiling the above code results in:

```
error: syntax error before `{' token
```

The Python equivalent of what I'm trying to achieve in C:

```py
def func(index):
    return [1,2,3,4,5][index]
```

Comment: `return (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[index];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the so-called *compound literals*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", 
       (int[]){1,2,3,4,5}[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Refer to C standard draft section [6.5.2.5 Compound Literals](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the point, but you could do this with compound literals in C:

```
int func(int index) {
   return (int[]){1, 2, 3, 4, 5}[index];
}
```

A better, more readable version:

```
int func(int index) {
   const int[] local = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   return local[index];
}
```

The generated machine code will be the same in either case.